Chrome Dev Tools 1024px breakpoint not working on Responsive
I have added a breakpoint for lg devices such that the hamburger menu appears for screens smaller than lg. However, on chrome dev tools, when the width is 1024, the hamburger menu is already triggered.
Responsive layout with the same 1024x740px layout:

I thought it was due to the scroll bar, and after debugging for a long time and playing around with the tools, I realized that the scroll bar is not the issue. When I hardcode the dimensions as 1024x740, I am able to get the correct Navbar. What is causing this issue, and how can I fix it?
Hardcoded 1024x740px layout:

Moreover, in the responsive mode, if I change device from desktop to mobile, it becomes the correct Navbar again.
Correct Navbar with Mobile Device Choice with 1024x740 layout:


All your images seem to display the behavior I expect from the description you gave: your first image has the viewport at 1022px width. This would be smaller than 1024px which is your lg breakpoint (if I understand correctly) and thus your hamburger menu should then appear since 1022px is smaller than 1024px.

you're right! i included the wrong screenshot. it was showing the hamburger menu even with the viewport at 1024 width, but after emptying cache and hard reload, it seems to be working correctly now :") thanks so much~
